# select statement displays full list but not in a select statement

Tags: coldfusion

I am struggling to find out where I have gone wrong, and have spent hours trying to find out why this is happening, I think its just something I have missed but I cant spot it.

What happens is that the select statement instead of showing a dropdown which i can just select a team to delete displays all of the teams in a list with a delete button next to it, yet when I use the select statement on another page it works fine. if anyone can point out where I have gone wrong that would be appreciated

Cheers

```
    <cfquery name="deleteteam" datasource="danny2">
    SELECT *
    FROM pool_teams
</cfquery>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LCF Delete Team</title>
</head>
<body>
    <cfif IsDefined('Form.delete_button')>
        <cfoutput>
            <form action="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="#FORM.ID#"/>
           do you really want to delete record?
           <input type="submit" name="confirm_button" value="Yes">
           <input type="submit" name="cancel_button" value="No">
           </form>
        </cfoutput>
    <cfelseif IsDefined('FORM.confirm_button')>
        <cfquery datasource="danny2">
            DELETE FROM pool_teams
            WHERE ID = '#FORM.ID#'
            </cfquery>
            The record has been deleted
            <cfoutput> <a href="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#">Return to list</a></cfoutput>

    <cfelseif IsDefined('FORM.cancel_button')>
        <cflocation url="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#" >

    <cfelse>
    <cfoutput query="deleteteam">
    <form action="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#" method="post">

        <select>
            <option value="#ID#">#teamname#</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="#deleteteam.ID#">
        <input type="submit" name="delete_button" value="delete"/>
    </form>
    </cfoutput>
    </cfif>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping out the right after the select statement?

Comment: *displays all of the teams in a list* Given that you are asking about a select "list", your description is a bit confusing ;-) Could you give an example, or post a screen shot?

Comment: ... also, realize that you're doing the `delete` *after* you have already pulled the results to display. That means you won't see the changes until the next time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<cfoutput query="deleteteam">
        <form action="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#" method="post">

            <select>
                <option value="#ID#">#teamname#</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="#deleteteam.ID#">
            <input type="submit" name="delete_button" value="delete"/>
        </form>
    </cfoutput>
```

This is where you are going wrong. If you think of outputting a query as performing a loop. each time you loop over the query you are making another form with one select option in it. 
You should change your code to look something like this.

```
 <form action="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#" method="post">
    <select>
         <cfoutput query="deleteteam">
            <option value="#deleteteam.ID#">#deleteteam.teamname#</option>
        </cfoutput>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="#deleteteam.ID#">
    <input type="submit" name="delete_button" value="delete"/>
</form>
```

What My code is doing is just adding options for each query item not the complete from. 
Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys that brill its been very frustrating, I think I understand now, so do i just end the loop

Comment: So how would I stop it from looping, sorry im pretty new at this

Comment: if you use cfoutput for a query it will loop over the query. So if you have 5 results the stuff in the output tag will be output 5 times. I moved the output inside the from so that you are only outputing the records not the form.

Comment: I can find the code to add a loop but it seems like I have to have a number where the loop becomes false, where in my situation more teams will be added, so I am a bit unsure how to make it scalable

Comment: I have posted the code that you have and the code you should change it to make it work.

Comment: Works perfectly cheers, and most of all I understand what Ive done, thanks again